# Как лучше реализовать длинную арифметику в C++?

Tags: c++

```
int64_t *data;
uint size;
```

Пусть число хранится так. Но что делать со знаком? хранить в самом левом бите или отдельно? И как лучше делать умножение деление сложение?

Comment: А зачем? Чем плохи существующие библиотеки?

Comment: В openssl например хранят отдельно

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4

Comment: Все в ваших руках. Где вам больше нравится, там и храните. Вопрос вообще не имеет смысла без указания выбранного кода. Если вы собрались использовать обратный или дополнительный код, то ни о каком "хранении отдельно" не может быть и речи - там нет никакого выделенного "знака". Если вы собрались использовать представление "знак и абсолютное значение", то можно хранить и отдельно. Какое представление вы будете использовать? Вы его уже выбрали?

Comment: Нужен вариант с большой скоростью расчёта. Дополнительный код вроде хорош тем что знак не имеет особого значения но вот при делении и умножении...

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков Тогда тем более непонятно зачем изобретать велосипед. Вряд ли вы напишите код который будет работать быстрее уже существующих

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то мне тоже понадобилась длинная арифметика. Но использовать GMP было нельзя, так как длинная арифметика нужна была для микроконтроллеров без операционной системы и кучи. Пришлось написать свою библиотеку С++ шаблонов для работы с длинными целыми числами. Вот ссылка:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/muntl/?source=frontpage&position=5

Там в архиве есть и описание на русском языке.